# Performance concern of defining functions in a `let` form

Tags: clojure

Is there any performance penalty for defining anonymous functions in a `let` form and calling the outer function repeatedly? Like this:

```
(defn bar [x y]
  (let [foo (fn [x] (* x x))]
    (+ (foo x) (foo y))))
```

Compared to defining `foo` as a separate function, like this:

```
(defn foo [x] (* x x))
(defn bar [x y] (+ (foo x) (foo y)))
```

I understood the lexical scope of `foo` is different in these two cases, I'm just concerned if the `foo` function would be *defined* over and over again when calling `bar` multiple times.

I guess the answer is *no*, i.e., there is no penalty for this, but how did clojure do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### `let` local approach:

`foo` is compiled only once (when the top-level form is). The result of this compilation is a class implementing the `clojure.lang.IFn` interface; the actual body lives in the `invoke(Object)` method of that class. At runtime, each time control reaches the point in `bar` where the `foo` local is introduced, a fresh instance of that class is allocated; the two calls to `foo` use that instance of that class.

Here is a simple way to prove the "single compilation" property at the REPL:

```
(defn bar [x y]
  (let [foo (fn [x] (* x x))]
    foo))

(identical? (class (bar 1 2)) (class (bar 1 2)))
;= true
```

NB. Clojure is smart enough to notice that `foo` is not an "actual closure" (it closes over the parameters of `bar`, but it doesn't actually use them), so the runtime representation of `foo` does not carry any extra fields that a closure would, but a fresh instance of `foo`'s class is nevertheless allocated on each call to `bar`.

#### Separate `defn` approach:

There is a single instance of `foo`, however calling it involves an indirection through a Var, which itself comes with a non-zero cost. That cost is generally not worth worrying about in all but the most performance-sensitive code, but it's there, so factoring out a local function may not necessarily be a performance win. As usual, if it's worth optimizing, it's worth measuring/benchmarking first.

#### `let` over `lambda`

There is also the final option mentioned by Daniel, where the `let` goes around, and not inside, the `defn`. With that approach, there is a single instance of (the class of) `foo`; it is stored in a field inside `bar`; and it is used for all calls to `foo` inside `bar`.

Comment: Excellent! Totally answered the question and offered more readings. By *penalty* I originally meant the compilation of the function `foo` into an `IFn` class. Since that is done only once, the cost of instantiating new objects is acceptable in my scenario I guess.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is yes, there will be a penalty for this but as Michael points out in the `let local approach` section, it is minimal.

If you want the lexical scoping as you described, then wrap the let block defining foo around the defn for bar. That will do what you are asking. However it is a pattern not commonly seen in Clojure code.